# AWS CloudFormation: unable to create RDS database because database security group cannot reference the web server's security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am building my infrastructure using AWS CloudFormation. I am creating a RDS database resource with a security group that is referencing another security group which is attached to the webserver. But it is failing when I deployed the template.

This is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredbidentifier'
  DBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredb'
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredbadmin'
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DBSecurityGroup
```

This is the error I got in the log.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/a710bab0-e1f5-11ea-8647-02dbc193ed28",
            "EventId": "b47b0660-e1f5-11ea-bedf-0ac92d082ee0",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/a710bab0-e1f5-11ea-8647-02dbc193ed28",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-19T08:26:39.929000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [DBSecurityGroup]. . Rollback requested by user."
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/a710bab0-e1f5-11ea-8647-02dbc193ed28",
            "EventId": "DBSecurityGroup-CREATE_FAILED-2020-08-19T08:26:39.217Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DBSecurityGroup",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "patheindirectory-DBSecurityGroup-AYJS8S8FDNCE",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-19T08:26:39.217000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Invalid id: \"patheindirectory-WebServerSecurityGroup-9KMFVDEWRVSF\" (expecting \"sg-...\") (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroupId.Malformed; Request ID: dec3b1d3-1259-
44cc-bdb9-84f4bf764df6)",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"GroupDescription\":\"Database security group\",\"SecurityGroupIngress\":[{\"FromPort\":\"3306\",\"ToPort\":\"3306\",\"IpProtocol\":\"tcp\",\"SourceSecurityGroupId\":\"patheindirectory-WebServerS
ecurityGroup-9KMFVDEWRVSF\"}]}"
        },
```

What is wrong with my template and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi. I saw your new question. Is it the same one as this one? Also wonder if the answer provided to this question was incorrect that new question needed to be posted?

Comment: Sorry.  I am only seeing the answer now. Yes, it is duplicate. Your answer works.

Comment: No problem. Glad it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [SourceSecurityGroupId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule-1.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-sourcesecuritygroupid) should be **ID of the security group**:

```
SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Thus, `DBSecurityGroup` should be:

```
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

The same goes for [VPCSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups) in `WebDatabase`:

```
  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

p.s.

`Region2Principal` is not used at all. Also,  password would be better as [NoEcho](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) type parameter:

```
  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: True
```

#### Corrected template in full (Region2Principal remains, but its not used here)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredbidentifier'
  DBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredb'
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Default: 'coredbadmin'
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: Number
    Default: 5
  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: True

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
```